# Creating resizable two panels with HTML & CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

So, I want to create two panels that are resizable with a horizontal draggable button. I showed in the picture below:

[image]

So, have it can be created with HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

#### What i tried first?

I used `interact.js`'s Resizable feature; but it didn't solve my problem. It just resized one panel, but I wanted to resize two panels at once.

##### The Code I tried:

```html
<style>
  .container {
    width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.container .section {
    resize: horizontal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container .section:nth-child(odd) {
    border-right: 5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}

.container .section:nth-child(even) {
    border-left: 5px solid rgb(17,17,17);
}
</style>
<div class="container">
   <div class="section">Section 0</div>
   <div class="section">Section 1</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
<script>
interact('.container .section:nth-child(odd)')
        .resizable({
            edges: { top: false, left: false, bottom: false, right: true },
            listeners: {
            move: function (event) {
                let { x, y } = event.target.dataset

                x = (parseFloat(x) || 0) + event.deltaRect.left
                y = (parseFloat(y) || 0) + event.deltaRect.top

                Object.assign(event.target.style, {
                width: `${event.rect.width}px`,
                height: `${event.rect.height}px`,
                transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
                })

                Object.assign(event.target.dataset, { x, y })
            }
            }
        })

        interact('.container .section:nth-child(even)')
        .resizable({
            edges: { top: false, left: true, bottom: false, right: false },
            listeners: {
            move: function (event) {
                let { x, y } = event.target.dataset

                x = (parseFloat(x) || 0) + event.deltaRect.left
                y = (parseFloat(y) || 0) + event.deltaRect.top

                Object.assign(event.target.style, {
                width: `${event.rect.width}px`,
                height: `${event.rect.height}px`,
                transform: `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
                })

                Object.assign(event.target.dataset, { x, y })
            }
            }
        })
</script>
```

What i wanted to do is; when I resized the second panel's width at 30% of viewport-width, the first panel's width will be at 70% of viewport-width.

Comment: PrimeNG has a [splitter](https://primeng.org/splitter) that does what you want. You might be able to find a more vanilla library that does the same using that term.

Comment: I have no idea how your stuff works, but maybe you could use css flex or something so that the second panel fills the remaining space so interact.js or whatever can just resize the first panel and the second panel resizes itself?

Comment: @i cant i used flex, but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry, I was kinda in a rush. I meant maybe you could set something like `.container { display: flex; }` and [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) on Section 1 (maybe with a `.section1` class or with [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)?) and just have interact.js resize the first panel, though I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired functionality, you can use the mousemove event on the draggable button to update the width of the two panels dynamically. Here's an example implementation using HTML, CSS, and vanilla JavaScript:

```js
const draggable = document.querySelector('.draggable');
const leftPanel = document.querySelector('.left-panel');
const rightPanel = document.querySelector('.right-panel');

let isDragging = false;
let initialWidth;

draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  isDragging = true;
  initialWidth = leftPanel.offsetWidth;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentWidth = initialWidth + event.clientX - draggable.offsetLeft;
    const containerWidth = leftPanel.offsetWidth + rightPanel.offsetWidth;
    const leftPanelWidth = (currentWidth / containerWidth) * 100;
    const rightPanelWidth = 100 - leftPanelWidth;

    leftPanel.style.width = `${leftPanelWidth}%`;
    rightPanel.style.width = `${rightPanelWidth}%`;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', (event) => {
  isDragging = false;
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.left-panel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.right-panel {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.draggable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel left-panel">
    <h2>Left Panel</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan in sem in aliquam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable"></div>
  <div class="panel right-panel">
    <h2>Right Panel</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus accumsan in sem in aliquam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this implementation, we use the mousedown event on the draggable button to set a flag that indicates the button is being dragged. We also store the initial width of the left panel.

On mousemove, we calculate the new width of the left panel based on the distance the mouse has moved since the mousedown event. We also calculate the new width of the right panel by subtracting the new left panel width from 100.

Finally, on mouseup, we clear the dragging flag to indicate that the button is no longer being dragged.

Note that this implementation assumes that the container element has a fixed height (in this case, 100vh). If the container's height can vary, you may need to adjust the calculations to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

See https://methodfish.com/Projects/MFPanels - there's some demos in the link and the code is shown under the Files or Releases link.

Code required is:

```
<script src='https://www.methodfish.com/Download/MFPanels/files/1.8/js/mfpanel.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet preload prefetch'  href='https://www.methodfish.com/Download/MFPanels/files/1.8/css/mfpanel.css'>
<style>
  .container { width:100%; height: 100% }
  #left      { width:25%; float:left;  }
  #center    { width:50%; float:left;  }
  #right     { width:25%; float:left;  }
</style>

<div class='container'>
    <div id='left'  class='resizable-e'></div>
    <div id='center' class='resizable-e'></div>
    <div id='right'></div>
</div>
```

a demo can also be played with using https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/xvtsf9rw/8/